# What was your extension idea at Tridion Developer Summit?

Tags: discussion

@RobertCurlette solicited SDL Web (Tridion) extension ideas from partners, customers, and SDL employees in an impromptu open session during the [Tridion Developer Summit 2015](http://2015.tridiondevelopersummit.com/2015/home/).

I noted about 25 ideas that were shared with the larger group. Please re-share if you presented. **But I also want to open this up to everyone that didn't have a chance to present.**

From the "free beer" button to displaying objects in a 3D graph, what was your idea?

Comment: We'll have video online later this week to inspire those not there or re-inspire those that were.  Thanks Alvin for this opportunity for the community to share here.

Answer (score 4):

My idea was to have a 'Watch item' button, which would allow a Tridion user to be notified if something happened to a specific item (or organisational item). For example:
 - If the item was published
 - If the item was updated
 - If the item was deleted

My original 'story' for this was to notify users when their item has been successfully published, rather than having to continually refresh (and potentially filter) the publishing queue.

Being able to report on deletion is also interesting, as otherwise, this action would have gone unnoticed (as the item isn't there any more - obviously!).

This is also useful to track changes to items that do not have a version history (Folders, Keywords, etc.).

At least I think that is what my idea was.... The TDS video should confirm. :)

Answer (score 2):

Extension to add a schema field, which you can bind to any cme list (+ filter options) within CME.
Make this field auto-complete friendly.

Answer (score 2):

My idea was a simple publish queue that didn't require constant refreshing.

A4T Extension can be installed from http://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/56093937e4de0211ecfc1c5f

Source: https://github.com/tridionted/Alchemy4Tridion.Plugins.RealTimePublishingStatus

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://ideas.sdltridion.com ;)

Comment: Sure. Of the 12 _product_ ideas you submitted, which one did you use at the developer summit? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't there but here's some:

- Keyboard shortcuts (configurable)
- Syntax highlighting
- Simple template editor (template builder lite - would save opening template builder to create simple templates or reorder)